# How to Call the Copy Activity Dynamically Single Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are executing pipeline one by one in sequence manager and load the data on premise SQL.
but we would want to load the data all the copy activity in single trigger. which means we have to load the 15 tables data into on premise DB. if tomorrow, we have to add one more table, we should not change in pipeline. we would like dynamic table insert. kindly advise.

thanks to all

Comment: Hey @Rakesh  you are master peace bro i want help from you for adf part i am stuck 
pls share your contact number or missed call me 8668496212

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the above scenario and got the below results.

**Use two lookups one for your source database and one for on-prem SQL.**

Here I have used Azure SQL database for both source and target. You can use your database with SQL Server linked service in lookup.

Use the below query in both lookups to get the list of tables.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM
information_schema.tables;
```

**lookup list of of source tables:**

[image]

Give the same query in second lookup.

**List of target tables with another lookup:**

[image]

Use filter activity to get the list of new tables which are not copied to target.

Items: `@activity('sql source lookup').output.value`

Condition: `@not(contains(activity('on-prem lookup').output.value,item()))`

[image]

**Filter result:**

[image]

Give this Value array to a ForEach activity and use copy activity inside ForEach.

[image]

**Copy Source:**

[image]

**Copy sink:**

[image]

You can see new tables are copied to my target. Schedule this pipeline everyday so that your every new table gets copied to target.

[image]

Comment: thanks lot for your help and doubt, my  source is adls gen2 and target is  on premise SQL. it will be work out, each folder different data coming from source, after that copy activity needs to load to target sql

Comment: If your source is ADLS gen2 and files level is same, instead of source lookup, you can use Get Meta activity with a wild card placeholder like `*/*/` to get the list of files. then you can do the same as above.

Comment: Inside Foreach also you can use wild card file path to copy activity source with `*/*/`(based on level) and `@item().name`.

Comment: If your files level is not same for all files, then you have to list the files recursively. Please go through this [article by Richardswinbank](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/get_metadata_recursively_in_azure_data_factory#:~:text=Roll%2Dyour%2Down%20iterative%20traversal,-An%20alternative%20to&text=Here's%20the%20idea%3A,them%20to%20the%20queue%20too).

Comment: my source adls having different folder and each folder partitioned files available

Comment: If the Folder structure and level is different for every file, then use the approach mentioned in the above link. AFAIK, Get Meta data won't give all files in the sub directories recursively so use that approach to get the file path and use that in copy activity source as well.

Comment: Hey @Rakesh you are master peace bro i want help from you for adf part i am stuck pls share your contact number or missed call me 8668496212